# Inconsistent results from Oracle's REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, oracle

Given a string of key-value pairs: `/* USER='Administrator'; UNV='Universe'; DOC='WebIntellignceReport'; */`

My goal is to extract values associated with the `USER`, `UNV`, and `DOC` keys.

Using a pattern of `(?<=UNV=')(.*?)(?=')`, I get the expected value of `Universe` associated the `UNV` key ([Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/uJiM7h/1)).

However, when I use the pattern with `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, I get a `NULL`:

```
SELECT  text
        ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'(?<=UNV='')(.*?)(?='')') UNV
FROM (
  SELECT  '/* USER=''Administrator''; UNV=''Universe''; DOC=''WebIntellignceReport''; */' as text 
  FROM    dual
) v
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Oracle regex does  not support lookarounds. Try `REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'UNV=''(.*?)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1) UNV`

Comment: You are testing these expressions using **pcrp(php)** regexp engine. This won't work on Oracle because it's regexp implementation is limited and doesnt support many features, see this link for details:  https://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html

Comment: Moreover, the query you posted (EXACTLY as posted) will not even pass compilation, since you are not handling single-quotes properly in the input string. If you post something for us to test, please test it yourself first, and fix it if it needs fixing.

Comment: @mathguy, upon closer inspection, my IDE (Datagrip) did correct the `/* ... */`syntax, so it worked.  Must have copied different source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the contents of group 1:

```
SELECT  text, REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'UNV=''(.*?)''', 1, 1 ,NULL, 1) UNV
FROM (
  SELECT  '/* USER=''Administrator''; UNV=''Universe''; DOC=''WebIntellignceReport''; */' as text 
  FROM    dual
) v
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/EWIH74791).

[image]

With `UNV='(.*?)'` , you may extract just what is between the closest single quuotes after`UNV=`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do is just grab the whole key-value pair using REGEXP_SUBSTR, and then do another substr to pull out the value you want.

```
with v as (select '/* USER=''Administrator''; UNV=''Universe''; DOC=''WebIntellignceReport''; */' as text from dual)
select text, key_val, substr(key_val, instr(key_val, '''')+1, length(key_val)-instr(key_val, '''')-2)
from (
    select text, 
    regexp_substr(text, ' UNV=''[^'']*'';') key_val 
    from v);
```

Output:

```
TEXT                                                                    KEY_VAL                                                                 VAL                                                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* USER='Administrator'; UNV='Universe'; DOC='WebIntellignceReport'; */  UNV='Universe';                                                        Universe
```